# Apache SSL Configuration

Tags: apache, tomcat

We are using apache tomcat 7.0 in our application. We need configure SSL but i want install the httpd apache on top the tomcat which would do ssl encryption and decryption. so it is possible have such configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use mod_proxy_http to proxy HTTPS requests back to HTTP request to the Apache Tomcat server.

So if you want all traffic to be served over HTTPS do the following:

Make sure tomcat is running on port 8080 (and not 80), install apache2 httpd and then:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod ssl
a2enmod rewrite
```

create a file called mysite.conf with the following VirtualHost directives:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.yourdomainname.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/www.yourdomainname.com.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/www.yourdomainname.com.key"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.yourdomainname.com
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally

```
a2ensite mysite
```